# Basis for the space of 4*4 hermitian matrices with specific anti-commutation properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The space of 2*2 hermitian matrices can be spanned using the basis involving identity and the three pauli matrices. Here, the pauli matrices have specific properties like:

1. When squared they give identity and
2. Each pair of them anti-commute and
3. Multiplication of any two of them again gives a pauli matrix except for a multiplicative factor.

Can we find a basis for 4*4 hermitian matrices such that the basis elements have the above properties? Can we at least find a set of basis matrices such that a subset of it satisfies the first two conditions and the whole set is closed under multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is yes.  Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ denote the Pauli matrices, and let $\sigma_0 = -I$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

The set 
$$
\{\sigma_i \otimes \sigma_j: 0 \leq i,j \leq 3 \}
$$
Is a basis for the $4 \times 4$ Hermitian matrices which is closed under multiplication.  Here, $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Note that the subsets 
$$
\{\sigma_i \otimes \sigma_0: 0 \leq i \leq 3 \},
\quad 
\{\sigma_0 \otimes \sigma_j: 0 \leq j \leq 3 \}
$$ 
act like the Pauli matrices.

---

What we have done here is take the tensor product of a representation of the quaternions with itself.  This new basis is indicative of a representation of $\Bbb H \times \Bbb H$, where $\Bbb H$ denotes the quaternion group.

Comment: What is the need of that negative sign in $\sigma_0=-I$?

Comment: Because squaring $\sigma_i^2=-I$ (for $i\neq 0$), and we want closure under multiplication.

Comment: Square of Pauli matrices is identity, right? Also, in the case of operator basis for a two dimensional Hilbert space we know that the set of three pauli matrices itself is closed under multiplication. Can we have a similar structure for higher dimension. i.e can the 15 matrices(excluding the identity) defined in your answer be closed under multiplication?

Comment: There seems to be no reason for the $-I$ after all; $I$ works just as well. I think these *are* closed under multiplication.

Comment: Yeah, it works for $I$ just as well. I know that the whole set of 16 matrices is closed under multiplication. But, can we make a basis in which 15 of the basis elements(except for the identity) itself is closed under multiplication?

Comment: I don't understand how that's supposed to be better... it is not possible to have 15 elements that are closed under multiplication and inverses which contains any one element that squares to the identity. That follows from Lagrange's theorem in group theory.

Comment: Because then I can form a transfer matrix for the evolution of a two-qubit system. Involving the identity will make the transfer matrix 16*16 instead of 15*15 and it is not easy to see how to simplify the 16*16 case.